# Unable to brew switch go versions

Tags: go, homebrew

I have go versions 1.13.1 and 1.12.9 installed

```
$brew list --versions | grep go
go 1.13.1
go@1.12 1.12.9
```

But I am unable to switch to 1.12, an error indicates that I only have version 1.13.1 installed contradicting the earlier listing.

```
$brew switch go 1.12
Error: go does not have a version "1.12" in the Cellar.
go installed versions: 1.13.1
```

And when I look carefully at go versions (no grep)

```
$brew list --versions go
go 1.13.1
```

So I must have done something wrong when I installed go 1.12, but what? I used `brew install go@1.12`, should I have used another syntax?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`go` and `go@1.12` are installed as two packages with different names, which means they are installed at different locations. `/usr/local/Cellar/go` and `/usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12`.

In this situation, you should use `brew link`.

```sh
brew unlink go

brew link go@1.12 --overwrite
```

---

#### Update 1

More explanation about `brew switch`. `brew switch <version>` is used to switch version installed with the same package name.

For example, If both `go` 1.13 and 1.13.1 installed, they're put in

- `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13`
- `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.1`

In this situation, use `brew switch`.

```sh
brew switch go 1.13
brew switch go 1.13.1
```

#### Update 2

`brew switch` has been [dropped since Homebrew 2.6.0](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/339#discussioncomment-246650).

Anyone still want the old `brew switch`, use the following tap, where `brew switch` is included as a custom sub-command.

```sh
brew tap laggardkernel/tap
brew switch --help
```

Comment: how to install different go versions with brew in order to be able to switch among them with brew switch?

Comment: brew switch no longer exists as a subcommand, sadly. not sure wtf happened but oooof.

Comment: @AlexanderMills A maintainer of homebrew once explained the reason to drop `brew switch` and replace it with `brew extract`. https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/339#discussioncomment-246650. But I don't buy it, `brew extract` doesn't cover my usage scenario. You can add it back as a custom command from a custom tap. https://github.com/laggardkernel/homebrew-tap/blob/master/cmd/switch.rb

Comment: seems like brew link / brew unlink can maybe do what brew switch does? but it will be global (will break anything running in parallel in different procs?) Ideally we have something that just switches the desired version in the current shell...

Answer (score -1):

Instead of switch, you can use [gvm Go Version Manager](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm).

1. `bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)`
2. `source ~/.gvm/scripts/gvm`
3. `gvm install go1.19`
4. `gvm use go1.19 [--default]`